# SecurityException - ConnectivityException (not always)

Tags: android, permissions, android-securityexception

A user reports on Google Play **ONLY** 3 times the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10103 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1327)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1281)
at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getActiveNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:597)
(...)
```

My AndroidManifest.xml contains the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

I think that it's all right because only this user reports this error. But why? It could be a device specific error, or device configuration error? The device is a Galaxy Tab 10.1 (GT-P7500) running Android 4.0.3-4.0.4 (Google Play data)

Comment: post your relevant code

Comment: post your code of asynctask